# reloading tire/elasticsearch mappings for a model that already has data stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongomapper, chef-infra, tire

I am using Tire and elasticsearch to provide search functionality on a MongoMapper model, which is part of a Rails App. I just stumbled across a problem where the mappings for this model were not being updated when I redeployed to an environment that uses the following configuration (in config/environments/env_name.rb):

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

reloading the class alone didn't seem to fix the issue (perhaps understandably, the new mappings might not be incompatible with existing data I guess?). instead I had to do the following:

```
MyModel.index.delete
<restart the app or reload the class>
MyModel.index.import MyModel.all
```

I just wondered if there's a better way of a). ensuring the latest mappings defined in my model code are being used by elasticsearch after each deployment but b). avoiding unnecessary repopulating the index  with the complete dataset?

We normally deploy using Chef, so I could automate the three steps I used successfully without too much trouble. But I'm new to elasticsearch and tire so I thought it's highly likely I'm misusing both or making things unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of points here:

- Tire tries to create the index with correct mapping when the class loads
- **but** Tire does **not** attempt to create the index for the model when it already exists

So, your question is really more about the proper workflow? When you deploy a new version of the application, you shouldn't re-populate the index, in the same way you don't re-populate the database from some kind of backup.

Automatically checking for index mappings conforming to current definition in the model is certainly possible (compare the `MyModel.tire.index.mapping` with `MyModel.tire.mapping`, re-populate if different, etc), it's something I'd be wary to do.

The developer usually knows when she changed the mapping and should re-index the data. Dropping the index, and re-populating also means search downtime, and isn't even feasible for large applications.

A nicer solution is to use a specific index name such as `my-index-2012-12` when importing the data, and point a `my-index` alias to this index. Then you can freely re-populate the index, and flip the alias when you're done, without downtime. Tire tries hard to support you in this kind of workflow (the Rake import task, etc).

Comment: I was a little confused by your last paragraph, I don't understand how  you can use an alias to another index to avoid downtown. In the scenario you described Won't searches against my-index just run against my-index-2012-12 while its being re-indexed?

Comment: Thanks for the details response. I'm going to mark this as correct, as I can't find an alternative. It seems like the jist of the answer is you will need to re-index the data in my scenario, and you can use elasticsearch aliases to avoid downtime in this scenario. Here's the link with more information on elasticsearch aliases: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-aliases.html The tire github page now links to this and has information on index aliases

Comment: @concept47 as per the tire github page now: You can index your data into a fresh index (and possibly update an alias once everything's fine). So you don't re-create the existing index, you create a new version then flip the alias. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @willjthomas Yes, correct. You index into new alias and flip the switch after you're done.

Comment: @karmi my `MyModel.tire.index.mapping` and `MyModel.tire.mapping` are different, but re-indexing doesn't appear to fix this (even with `FORCE=true`. How am I supposed to proceed?

Comment: If they're different, it means your model definition contains different mapping then your index. Either drop the index and re-index from DB, or reindex by Elasticsearch (search Tire tests for `reindex`), or index into different index and use alias...